# Outlook 2010 doesn't like it when I tell it NOT to "Remember Password" for Gmail?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail-imap

When I uncheck the "Remember Password" box, Outlook gives me an error when synchronizing, instead of asking me for my Gmail password. It works fine when I tell it to remember the password, though...

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing the password first from "protected storage" (in accounts) then tell it not to remember?

Comment: @Psycogeek:  :O no! How do I do that?

Comment: set it back the way it was, go into accounts as if you were going to change the password, then remove it instead.  then turn off the remember.  To remove using other methods like registry, I would have to know the OS (and it would still take some time to figure out)

Comment: @Psycogeek: I'm not sure if I did this correctly or not (I'm on Windows 7), but after following what you just wrote, when I start Outlook, I get: `Your IMAP server closed the connection.` `[UNAVAILABLE] Temporary System Error
 Protocol: IMAP
 Server: imap.gmail.com
 Port: 993
 Error Code: 0x800CCCDD`.

Comment: oops, that happens when your password is changed. can you just remove the account and remake it? also Gmail can use POP.

Comment: @Psycogeek: I want IMAP, not POP. :P I also tried deleting the account, but same problem. (Note that SMTP *does* ask for my password when sending a test email -- but IMAP doesn't.)

Comment: Click the Security tab and click the check box for "Always prompt for logon credentials"?

Comment: @Psycogeek: Huh? I don't see a "Security" tab anywhere...

Comment: in accounts .  see also http://superuser.com/questions/263743/windows-7-never-remembers-my-password-credential and http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Remove-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials  .  The reason I was wondering about the stored passwords, is it would defeat the purpose of having to entering it when it is Stored on your machine anyway.

Comment: @Psycogeek: Are you sure that's even relevant to my issue? The "security" tab seems to be for Exchange...

Comment: No I am not sure , it does apply to exchange.

Comment: @Psycogeek: Well I don't see any "Security" tab anywhere, and neither is there anything stored in my Windows credentials.

Comment: Well I am not much help. the fact that one protocol type works but the other doesnt is a clue. Is this the registry location for the passwords data? (not settings) HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles

Comment: @Psycogeek: I tried clearing everything in Outlook (even deleting all my Profiles, from the Control Panel, which deleted that registry key) but same issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

The dialog box pictured in the question has the title 'Test Account Settings.' In the 'Change Account' window, uncheck 'Test Account Settings' before clicking the Next Button. This will cause your client to wait until the next email sync to prompt you for your password.

Be aware!! Gmail IMAP has [known issues](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78754&topic=1668982&ctx=topic) with clients requesting to authenticate "too often." Among other things, this may flag your account to require passing a CAPTCHA to continue syncing. Visit https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha to attempt the unlock and then try your sync again. On [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14257) Google specifically recommends configuring your client to remember the password.